# Where's this picture of a glacial moraine in autumn taken?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, photography

[image]

This picture's from [r/autumn](https://redd.it/bwketm). I searched with Google Images but no result!

1. Is there a geographical term for this landscape?
2. Can I access this by private automobile?

Comment: The end of a glacier is called the "terminal moraine"

Comment: Is it an actual photograph or artwork? It is signed, which is unusual for a photograph. The peaks in front of the sun don't quite match the rest of the image, and the bough in the foreground looks like a tree trunk rotated right.

Comment: Also, there is no place where leafed trees are at the tree line.

Comment: @Janka Of course there is. The mountain birch grows along the tree line across the entire northern Europe and one of publications of this image attributes it to Patagonia, where there are also many varieties of beech, growing up to the tree line. The image still looks like a painting or drawing and not a photograph.

Comment: I should have added *only* to my comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane: In view of the answers, someone has to link https://xkcd.com/331/...

Comment: @Janka That wouldn't have made it more correct. In Norway, there are large areas, where except for shrubbery, the only trees growing at the tree line are birches. I've never been to Patagonia, but judging from the many photographs found online, which resemble this scene very much, the same is true there for the beech.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a picture of Cerro Torre, in Patagonia, Argentina. This view appears similar to the one from the Pliegue Tumbado trek  (https://elchalten.com/v4/en/pliegue-tumbado-trek-el-chalten.php). It is a 7-8 hour return hike, with an elevation change of 1100 m, from the town of El Chaltén (the closest road access).

Answer (score 6):

Doing a google search for the signature at the bottom of the image results in an Instgram page with page for the post - https://www.instagram.com/p/ByQF62KoVsU/ - the post indicates that this is a photo taken in Patagonia (Arginentia), it seems likely that this is the case as the same post includes another photo with the same background but a different foreground, likely taken from a few steps to the side. Although that said, I suspect a healthy dose of post-processing enhancement has taken place.

Comment: The comment by the photographer states “I waited the whole day at this location and hoped for some nice sunset colors. Well, I'd say the plan worked out well. :) “, so it could be close to original.

Comment: "includes another photo" - the two images are identical, just cropped differently. Nonetheless absolutely beautiful!